# Делать Scroll пока не найдет элемент на сайте

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Пытаюсь сделать небольшую программку. Суть - На сайте есть элемент ,который я ищу через xpatch. Но чтобы он был виден Selenim- у , нужно сделать "скролл" и не один..... Очень хотелось бы реализовать это через whill но никак не получается......

Прошу сильно не лупить за код..., начал изучать python совсем недавно:)

Первая часть кода ищет нужный элемент по  "xpatch"  и когда находит - то кликает по нему.
Вторая часть (где else) делает "скролл" если найдет " html"  в CSS_SELECTOR-ре (а он есть всегда на сайте). Должно получится так - что все это будет "скроллится"  пока не найдет элемент по "xpatch".

```
while True:
if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/center/form/button"):
    time.sleep(3)
    knopra_vupolnenia = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/center/form/button")
    time.sleep(3)
    knopra_vupolnenia.click()

else:
        knopra_vupolnenia = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html")
        time.sleep(2)
        knopra_vupolnenia.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
```

Скажите что я не так делаю.
Очень Буду очень признателен за любые подсказки и советы!

---

весь код если что...

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By                         import time                                                      
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


options = Options()
options.add_argument('-profile')
options.add_argument(r'C:\Users\werty\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\6w07oelt.proffffffff')
options.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver.get("https:......ru")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)


while True:
    if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/center/form/button"):
        time.sleep(3)
        knopra_vupolnenia = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/center/form/button")
        time.sleep(3)
        knopra_vupolnenia.click()

    else:
            knopra_vupolnenia = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html")
            time.sleep(2)
            knopra_vupolnenia.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда я запускаю ваш код, то получаю ошибку, что элемент не найден:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/center/form/button
```

Поэтому скрипт останавливается. Можно обработать эту ошибку с помощью `try except`, чтобы скрипт не останавливался, если выбрасывается это исключение. Также у вас нет выхода из бесконечного цикла `while True`, если элемент найден.

Если брать за основу приведенный вами код, то это будет так:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1456869/")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)


while True:
    try:
        knopra_vupolnenia = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/center/form/button")
        if knopra_vupolnenia: # если переменная непустая, т.е. элемент найден
            knopra_vupolnenia.click()
            break # прервать цикл
        time.sleep(3)


    except NoSuchElementException as E: # обработать исключение, что элемент не найден
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html").send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
```

`send_keys(Keys.DOWN)` прокручивает страницу совсем чуть-чуть. Вместо этого можете использовать:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

или:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500);") # вместо 500 можете вписать любое кол-во пикселей для прокрутки вниз
```

Также попроюуйте, может, вам достаточно будет прокрутить страницу в конец 1 раз вместо цикла:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html").send_keys(Keys.END)
```

Дополнение: вариант с `if, else:`

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1456869/")
driver.set_page_load_timeout(20)

while True:
    knopra_vupolnenia = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/center/form/button")  # список
    if knopra_vupolnenia: # если переменная непустая, т.е. элемент найден
        knopra_vupolnenia[0].click()  # [0] - индекс элемента в списке knopra_vupolnenia
        break  # прервать цикл
    else: # если список knopra_vupolnenia пустой
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "html").send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
```

Comment: Ok огромное Вам Спасибо! Это точто я и хотел.! Но мне все ещё не понятна одно. Я вот как размышлял, когда писал код: если 1 условие не нашло xpath, то else должно ведь сработать....?  И так по кругу - пока не найдёт xpath..... Можно ли все это "организовать", просто - только через whill  и else?. 
 Только начинаю разбираться в программировании и какие то моменты упускаю.  Ps: Ещё раз Большая Вам Благодарность за подсказку.

Comment: Вы правильно размышляли. Проблема лишь в том, что ```driver.find_element``` выбрасывает ошибку, если элемент не найден, и скрипт прерывается. Но есть выход: ```driver.find_elements``` ищет не один элемент,  а все элементы, соответствующие условию и не выбрасывает ошибку, если таких элементов нет. Тогда достаточно только ```if``` и ```else```. Я добавил в ответ такой вариант. Буду благодарен, если нажмете принять ответ)

Comment: Нажал принять ответ.Ещё раз низкий Вам поклон за помощь в моем освоении python!